# Maven compile dependency instead of taking it out of the local repo

Tags: java, svn, maven, dependencies, local

I am sorry i don't know maven good enough for the complex environment i am currently working in (1k+ applications, most of them are Java EE). I still give it a try to describe what i want to archive:

0.) There is a company framework that abstracts the Java EE World a bit and is used in all the Java EE components

1.) I checked out the maven project of the Java EE component i am working with 
    during the build it downloads the dependencys of other components out of the companys  repository and stores it inside my local repo for compilation. So i can see the jar-files of the companys framework inside my local repo.

2.) I now want to change some of the frameworks functionality for a local test so i checked out their sources from another SVN repository. I made the changes and build that framework component with maven "clean install".

3.) I rebuild the component i am working with as well.

Inside eclipse i can now click on one of a frameworks classes method and it opens the according source. But this only happens because the local repo is meant to contain source-jars for any dependency as well. So in my editor i can see this source is from the jar of the framework in my local repo and i cant change anything.

Could someone please give me a hint how i can archive the following:

- I can make changes to the framework (and build the frameworks jars with "clean install")
- I can build my component and it uses the above compiled framework jars rather than the "old" ones from the local repo.

I will right now start to read the entire maven documentation and each and every section (i try to understand that dependency management since 1 year and still don't get it) but i would really appreciate if you could help me out a bit here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how Eclipse manages maven dependencies, but

In IntelliJ IDEA this is simple - if maven dependency is in project then IDEA uses it instead of dependency from local repo.

So if u want to edit framework source code and use this changes immidiately - i think that framework should be in your Eclipse Workspace. And your module in Eclipse should reference framework artifacts directly - not over Maven dependency mechanism.

I think that this is a Eclipse Maven plugin responsibility. Do u have any installed Maven plugin for Eclipse? (M2Eclipse for example)

Comment: Many thanks for you answer as faar as i understood you right i will remove the dependency from within the components pom and tell eclipse "those (framework) projects" are dependencys of my component. I will give it a try.

Comment: Don't remove dependencies from POM. Maven build should always work independently of IDE you are using. Did u try to install M2Eclipse?

Comment: I recognized that the framework library used has version 5.0.4, the one i build resides in the local repo as well but has version 5.0.3-Snapshot. I have now declared the dependency inside my pom to that version (5.0.3) in the hope that a rebuild will then use this. (Since i cant build the component from within eclipse in no time to produce the correct EAR to deploy for local tests)

Comment: As faar as ic it already used the M2Eclipse Plugin but i will recheck that.

Comment: Ok M2Eclipse plugin is there. I think your answer got me on the right track. I see the framwork libarys in my local repository but they have a lower build number (5.0.3-Snapshot) than the others there (they are all 5.0.4 or above). I changed that in the dependency version-tag and can rebuild now... hopefully this makes the changes active in my component. Many thanks!